# How can I shorten the amount of time it takes to change variables dependent on environment (QA/Dev/Prod)

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java Project, and I wrote a small plug-in to the existing project. I wrote it on my Mac(dev), QA is on Windows and Prod is on Unix.

In the code I make specific API calls to a different program. On my mac though I'm just reading in a file. In Dev it is using windows file path to execute an external programs CLI. Prod will be the same.

I'm aware of property files, should I use a property file for this to quickly switch environments.

At the moment it is just a lot of commenting/uncommenting to get everything up and running.

Comment: I am not a java expert but can't you detect the environment from within the code and simply use an if/then statement?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the code inside any `if (EnvironmentIsProd){..}` statements are never run before being seen by customers.  Is this a case for [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

Comment: I guess you meant "in **QA** [environment] it is using windows file path ...". And how can your program do "the same" in Prod - are there any "windows file paths" in your Unix environment? And what do you mean by "windows file path"? A hardcoded path in your application? The "path" environment variable? Please edit your question and make it a little bit more precise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution IMHO would be to completely avoid making any differences between those 3 environments in your Java program's code. So why don't you just provide a more or less simple command line program in your Mac environment (which is in fact a Unix environment, too) which takes exactly the same parameters as the external programs in the other 2 environments, and returns results in a compatible form? The path to this program should be configured by some kind of configuration file, outside of your Java source code.